# MySQL Error phpmyadmin create table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have problem

```
CREATE TABLE acct_v4_%Y_%m_%d (

    ip_src CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    ip_dst CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    src_port INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    dst_port INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ip_proto CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    packets INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    bytes BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    stamp_inserted DATETIME NOT NULL,
    stamp_updated DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (ip_src, ip_dst, src_port, dst_port, 
    ip_proto, stamp_inserted)
```

);

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%Y'*'%m'*'%d' ( ip_src CHAR(15) NOT NULL, ip_dst CHAR(15) NOT ' at line 1

Why does this error come about?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/writing-tests-naming-conventions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a table name with the `%` character, check this [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
> ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar,
>   underscore)